# Preventing website, from storing Stripe Credit Card Number

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

How is it assured that Stripe Credit Card Number is not accessible from JavaScript?

Created stripe custom form.

```
<form action="/payment/post" method="post">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="firstName" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="AB" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-locale-reversible>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input id="payment-name" data-tid="form.name_placeholder" class="input empty" type="text" placeholder="@Model.name" required="">
                            <label for="payment-name" data-tid="form.name_label">Cardholder Name</label>
                            <div class="baseline"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="field">

                        <div id="payment-card-number" class="input empty"></div>
                        <label for="payment-card-number" data-tid="form.card_number_label">Card number</label>
                        <div class="baseline"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

On submission of form:
I pick firstname and attempting to read card number as well (which should not be allowed)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/payment/post',
data: JSON.stringify({
    name: name.value,
    token: result.token.id,
    firstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
    cardNumber: $("input[name='payment-card-number']").val() **I know that it is not posted to server, for understanding purposes, how it ensured**
}),
```

EDIT:
On insspecting card number input text box. I noticed, payment-card-number input element is generated by Stripe js.

```
<input type="tel" autocomplete="cc-number" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="payment-card-number" class="InputElement is-complete" aria-label="Credit or debit card number" placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234" aria-placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234" aria-invalid="false" value="5555 5555 5555 4444">
```

> Is it already enforced by Stripe library in some way? What is that
>   approach.

Stripe V2 Api didn't require, IFrame, however V3 requires IFrame (can't say for sure, but all examples I have seen requires IFrame). Is this the way of encorcing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Stripe ensure that Card number is not stored by website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549543/how-does-stripe-ensure-that-card-number-is-not-stored-by-website)

Comment: `Is this the way of enforcing?` Yes, you should use [Stripe.js v3](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js)(i.e Elements) as this uses the iframe approach meaning that Javascript on your page does not have sensitive card information. If you use v2 you also have a harder time being PCI compliant : https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance

Comment: @karllekko, I believe thats all community has to say, post this is an answer, will mark it correct, for benefits of others looking for similar info. Thanks!